# How to reshape long format data and count the values

Tags: r, reshape, plyr, melt

I think this is a basic question, but it seems to be frustrating me...

I am using R and have data in long format; a data.frame with each value a string. I want to produce a summary table of the counts of each value. So for the data:

| Location | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| North | red |
| North | blue |
| North | red |
| South | red |
| South | red |
| North | red |
| South | blue |
| North | blue |
| South | red |
| South | red |

I would like to produce the summary table:

| Location | red | blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 3 | 2 |
| South | 4 | 1 |

I've tried numerous attempts of reshape and cast. I'm drawing a blank as there are no numeric 'values' in the table.

Comment: Simple, there's a built-in: `table(df1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tabyl` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
tabyl(df1, Location, Colour)
 Location blue red
    North    2   3
    South    1   4
```

Answer (score 2):

With tidyverse, `dplyr::count()` first, then pivot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  count(Location, Colour) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Colour, values_from = n)
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   Location  blue   red
#   <chr>    <int> <int>
# 1 North        2     3
# 2 South        1     4
```

In base R, you can use `table()`:

```
table(Location = dat$Location, dat$Colour)
# Location blue red
#    North    2   3
#    South    1   4
```

Note, however, that the output of `table()` isn't a data.frame, so may not work for you depending on what your next step is.

Answer (score 2):

Also using `table()`:

```
df |>
  with(table(Location, Colour)) |>
  rbind() |>
  as_tibble(rownames = "Location")

  Location  blue   red
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 North        2     3
2 South        1     4
```

Reproducible data

```
df = data.frame(
  Location = c("North", "North", "North", "South", "South", "North", "South", "North", "South", "South"), 
  Colour = c("red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red" )
)
```

Comment: Thank you - `table()` was the method which was eluding me!

If anyone should find this in future... adding a `as.data.frame.matrix()` converts the table to a dataframe

Comment: The problem with `as.data.frame()` is having Location in row names.